# Power Jack connection switch pin?

Tags: connector, components, identification

I was looking at a this [CUI power jack connector](http://www.cui.com/Product/Resource/DigiKeyPDF/PJ-002AH.pdf) and I noticed that it has a switch which is NC, and I think goes open when a connector is plugged in (pin 2/3).

There's no clear distinction I can make out between which pin (pin 2 or 3) which is actually electrically hooked up to the outer housing (in my case ground since my adapter is center positive).

Which pin should I connect my ground to? If I don't need to detect if the jack is plugged in, can I just short out the two pins and not worry about the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pin numbers of the connector are identified in the data sheet that you linked, both on the small schematic and on the footprint/hole diagram.

Here is an annotation of the connector schematic.

[image]

As drawn the connector barrel pushes down on the contact and opens the point switch contact to pin 3.

Comment: I can't tell from the schematic which is which.

Comment: The pin numbers of the connector are labeled in the drawing on nearly every view. In the schematic the connector view for pin 2 shows the actual connection that contacts the outside barrel contact. I'll add a picture to my answer.